# PHP DOMDocument - Get all elements on the first top-level

Tags: php, domdocument

I would like to find all elements in the $content without children.

With my actual code, I find all elements with child (strong, ahref, ...).

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->resolveExternals = false;
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$html->substituteEntities = false;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
libxml_clear_errors();

/** @var DOMElement $node */
foreach ($html->documentElement as $node) {
    dump($node->nodeName, $node->nodeValue);
}
```

My $content variable is:

```
<p>lorem</p>
<p><strong>lorem</strong> ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<h2>test</h2>
<p>test</p>
```

I want get all elements `p`, and `hX` to detect if it's a paragraph, or figure in paragraph, or title, etc...

Comment: DOMNode has a `childNodes` property, https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes You have no real root element here that you could use this on, but wrapping your content into an additional `<div>…</div>` could help with that. Otherwise, you can also try and use XPath.